# VideoView on top of WebView

Tags: android, focus, android-videoview

I have a Tab with a WebView inside displaying a list of Videos from a homepage. Once I click on a Video I setContentView(video) which is a XML holding only a VideoView. I added an onCompletionListener to the VideoView, so when the video is over, i would like to setContentView(webview). My LogCat shows me that the WebView is loading but i never shows up. screen stays black. How do i get the focus back to the WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using two different layouts and calling setContentView() when you want to switch I think you should put your WebView and VideoView into the same layout, and use `View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` and `View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` to control which one is being shown at the appropriate times.

Comment: Ok that worked half way. It loads the Webview nicely. Then it plays the Video working perfect.. Problem is the area where the video was played stays black.. the bottom loads the Webview..

Comment: videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE) did the trick!! Thanks for your help!